# Modern, Clear Mathematics books with a similar style to Sheldon Axler's books

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

## This list *"is All You Need"*

I graduated in Mathematics a couple of years ago but I know feel that I am forgetting quite a few things so I would like to go over *most* of the mathematical syllabus on my own.

I would like to build a physical library (**meaning I want to buy books, not read them online**). I am looking to fill the areas shown below. Importantly, I would like to have books that are clear, fairly modern (I struggle to read 100-year-old manuscripts but if there is no alternative, I'll go for an old book) and allow me to cover the areas below without many gaps.

Can you please suggest **books following a similar style to Sheldon Axler**'s "Linear Algebra Done Right" and "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis"? By similar style I mean that they take the reader by hand and reinforce topics by using different colors, repetition of concepts and, importantly, building a lot of intuition with diagrams, figures or examples. They also shouldn't be huge 1000-page-long bricks.

Here are the areas I am trying to cover. Striken over text means I have already bought them and happy with them. Texts in parenthesis are books I heard are good but possibly not quite similar to Sheldon Axler's style.

| Area | Found | Book |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Calculus | No | [C - Spivak](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Calculus-Michael-Spivak/dp/0521867444) or [VCLADF - Hubbard](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Vector-Calculus-Linear-Algebra-Differential/dp/0136574467) |
| <s>Linear Algebra</s> | Yes | [LADR - Axler](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Linear-Algebra-Right-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387982582) |
| Analysis | Maybe | [A1- Tao](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789811017896) or [UA - Abbot](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789811017896) |
| Metric Spaces | Maybe | [A2 - Tao](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789811018046) or [PMA - Rudin](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Principles-Mathematical-Analysis-International-Mathematics/dp/007054235X) |
| Differential Geometry | No |  |
| Functional Analysis | Maybe | [FAFA - Sasane](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Friendly-Functional-Essential-Textbooks-Mathematics/dp/1786343347) or [IFAA - Kreyszig](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introductory-Functional-Analysis-Applications-Classics/dp/0471504599) or [FA - Stein](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Functional-Analysis-Introduction-Princeton-Lectures/dp/0691113874) |
| <s>Measure Theory</s> | Yes | [MIRA - Axler](https://measure.axler.net/) |
| Probability | Maybe | [PI - Grimmett](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Introduction-Geoffrey-Grimmett/dp/0198709978) or [PT - Klenke](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447153610) or [PM - Billingsley](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Measure-3rd-Patrick-Billingsley/dp/8126517719) |
| ODEs | No | [DEDSLA - Hirsch](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Differential-Equations-Dynamical-Systems-Mathematics/dp/0123495504) |
| Dynamical Systems | Maybe | [NDC - Strogatz](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nonlinear-Dynamics-Chaos-Applications-Nonlinearity/dp/0738204536) |
| Stochastic Differential Equations | No |  |
| Optimization | No |  |
| Differential Calculus | Maybe | [DCNS - Cartan](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Differential-Calculus-Normed-Spaces-Analysis/dp/154874932X) or [VCLADF - Hubbard](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Vector-Calculus-Linear-Algebra-Differential/dp/0136574467) |
| Statistics | Maybe | [NSLT - Vapnik](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387987804) or [SLT - Vapnik](https://www.wiley.com/en-gb/Statistical+Learning+Theory-p-9780471030034) |

Comment: Spivak's *Calculus* is a baby analysis single-variable calculus book; it is superb. You're thinking of his *Calculus on Manifolds*, which I do *not* recommend. I wrote a far more accessible text (incorporating and integrating linear algebra — of course, you know the linear algebra quite well), which of course I am obliged to recommend. You can also download my undergraduate differential geometry text for free (see the link in my profile).

Comment: "By similar style I mean that they take the reader by hand and reinforce topics by using different colors, repetition of concepts and, importantly, building a lot of intuition with diagrams, figures or examples" - This is almost the exact opposite of the style of Rudin's analysis book, so I would suggest striking that one from your list. An alternative that is much more aligned with your desired style would be Abbott's [Understanding Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/1493927116).

Comment: +1 for Ted Shifrin's multivariable calculus book, btw!

Comment: @Bungo Thank you! I had a look at the table of contents and it looks great! It does seem to have a similar style to Axel's!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you! I looked at the table of contents and I like the fact that Stoke and Green's theorems are covered! I should look into it!

Comment: @Euler_Salter Even if graphically they aren't as polished as Axler's books I highly recommend Terence Tao's Analysis I and II books: they are superb. He explains how to build real analysis literally from 0 explaining every step. I also recommend, as others before me, Spivak's Calculus, Hubbard/Hubbard's Multivariable Calculus and Shifrin's Multivariable Mathematics.

Comment: @lorenzo They look amazing!

Comment: Are you looking for probability at the undergraduate level or at the PhD level? If at the PhD level, you are going to have a very hard time. For functional analysis, I'm just starting to learn from this myself, but you may want to consider *A Friendly Approach to Functional Analysis* by Sasane. An alternative to Rudin's text for analysis is *Real Mathematical Analysis* by Pugh.

Comment: @Clarinetist I would like Probability at PhD level if possible. Mainly because once I have mastered Measure Theory, Analysis, Metric Spaces and Functional Analysis I should be able to read a fairly advanced textbook. How come you think I am going to have a very hard time? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I have about 20 textbooks in PhD probability, and probability is one of my favorite subjects (go look at the tags under my profile if you don't believe me). They are all quite frankly terrible. The only one that is somewhat tolerable in my experience is *Probability Theory* by Klenke, but it is nowhere near the standard you're looking for.

Comment: @Clarinetist I have really struggled to find a good Probability book too. Klenke's one is good in the sense that at least it is theoretical but I agree it doesn't have as good as a standard as I am currently looking for. I had a look at Billingsley *Probability and Measure* but it is quite old and I wish it had a bit more intuition

Comment: @Euler_Salter Billingsley's text is revered for its completeness and has stood the test of time as a reference. I would never use it on its own for learning. Many probability books at this level that are respected seem to have a similar vibe among them.

Comment: @Clarinetist BTW thank you for the suggestions for Functional Analysis and Analysis. Do you know of any Functional Analysis text that is a bit more geared towards probabilists or statisticians?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Prob/stats is my area of specialty, and I haven't found any. I think the problem with finding a functional analysis text geared toward stats, in particular, is that functional analysis is usually treated as a branch of math, separate from stats (at least based on what I've observed).

Comment: for ODEs I think Hirsch and Smale's text is amazing; I also paired it with Lawrence Perko's text on ODEs. These two books have similar flavor focusing a lot on the linear algebra aspect, especially 2x2 systems and 3x3 systems and their geometric interpretations (I also read Henri Cartan's book on differential calculus which is an amazing book, but I'm not sure if it's something you might like)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for the advice! Do you mean [Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387951164)? Also I am definitely interested in differential calculus! I shall add it as a new topic cause I forgot about it! What prerequisites does it have?

Comment: yes that's the one. FOr prerequisites to Perko, basic linear algebra is a must (linear transformations, rank, kernel, eigenvalues,eigenvectors etc all the basics). A good understanding of multivariable differential calculus is a must (i.e derivatives as linear transformation, basic rules like product and chain rule). Also, single-variable analysis is a MUST eg $\epsilon$-$\delta$ notion of limits, continuity, some basic point-set topology (open, closed, compact, connected sets) and also things like uniform convergence and stuff (all of which you can easily pick up in Rudin's first book).

Comment: For functional analysis, Kreyszig is often recommended. Stein and Shakarchi's text is also nice; every book in their 4-part series is well-written.

Answer (score 4):

For calculus (multivariable calculus and differential forms) I highly recommend Hubbard and Hubbard. It is very clear and written with great care. For dynamical systems, Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos by Strogatz is a great book that you will like a whole lot.

For differential geometry, I recommend Needham's new book Visual Differential Geometry and Forms, which will be published July 2021.

Comment: Looking at the table of contents, I like how the author goes through 1D and 2D first